# What does "break on someone " mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

> I mentioned apartment issues earlier and there were many. Things were either not functional when we got the keys or would easily **break on us**

I'm assuming things would malfunction when they're trying to use it. For example, a stuck door falls on you when you pull on it hard or the oven starts making weird sounds when you switch it on for the first time.

Comment: *It broke on me = It broke **when I was using it*** (it "failed / let me down").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a person or thing *does something* **on** *someone* that usually means that the first person or thing has failed to do something, or has disappointed the second person in an annoying way:

I couldn't get to work on time because my car broke down on me.

Joe tried to call me, he said, but his phone's battery died on him.

I had a date with Mary, but she cancelled on me.

Cambridge Dictionary gives the 'faulty thing, machine or gadget' meaning, but, at least in the UK, a person can be talked about  in this way if they unexpectedly fail to do something expected or promised:

> on preposition (FAULTY)
>
> used to show who suffers when something does not operate as it should:
>
> *The phone suddenly went dead on me*.
> *Their car broke down on them on the way home.*

[On (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on)

Comment: I wouldn't categorize the car breaking down like the rest of the examples. That reads to me as "[while] on the way home", describing when/where the car broke down, rather than describing who was affected by the car breaking down, which would be "broke down on me".

Comment: @Feathercrown that's exactly what's written, though. "because my car broke down *on me*," "Their care broke down *on them* on the way home." The people who were in the car are the ones affected, and are the objects of "on" here.

Comment: @Esther I totally missed the "on them" in that sentence-- whoops

Comment: I can't think of an example where "on" is correct, but does not indicate that something is in ongoing use.

Comment: @fectin - I am not sure what you mean. 'Ongoing use' means 'not interrupted use'. If my car breaks down on me, or my horse goes lame on me, they will definitely **not** be in 'ongoing use', and will not be in use at all until they are fixed. If my phone's battery dies on me, the phone will not be in use again until I charge it. If a cheap cell phone dies on me, I will most likely put in in the trash, and it will never be in use again.

Comment: Things that you are not using just "break," they don't break "on you".

Comment: @fectin - you are not making sense.